# Updated form data not getting to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, model-view-controller

**Scenario:** The user wants to edit some details for an existing profile. Issue is that when the form is submitted, in the controller the updated value for that attribute *(example: country)* is not present. It still contains the old value that was there before the edit. Using the network tab in the chrome developer console, I verified that upon submission, the form sent the new value but in the controller, it is gone.

The form which contains the field:

```
<form:form id="userDetailsForm" commandName="userForm">
    <div id="userCountryWrapper">
        <label>Enter Country:<label>
        <form:input path="userCountry" id="userCountry" value="${userForm.userCountry}" />
    </div>
</form:form>
```

The controller where I am receiving the data:

```
public String getFormData (@ModelAttribute("userForm") @Valid UserForm userForm, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    ..
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    userEntity.setCountry(userForm.getCountry);
    ..
}
```

Any inputs/suggestions to why this data loss maybe happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in your controller and to be more specific i think you must to change the line `UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();` because you create a new object rather than update it, a simple solution i think is use something like this `userEntinty = userRepository.findUserById(userForm.getUserId).orElseThrow(() -> { new Exception })`;
`userEntity.setCountry(userForm.getCountry)`;
`userRepository.save(userEntinty);`
Im not sure but you can check it and then tell us the solution

Comment: I get what you're saying but even if I do that, the issue doesn't change right? The data from the form is not coming to the controller so that's the pain point I need to figure out. Thanks for the suggestion anyways!

Comment: Ok yeah i understand that, so maybe the problem is that the form doesn't contain the action and the method attributes

Answer (score 0):

To pass the data from form to controller, thymeleaf can be used.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/getformdata}" th:object="${userForm}" method="POST">
    <label>Enter Country:<label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{userCountry}">
    <button type="submit" >save user</button>
</form>
```

To use thymeleaf attributes in HTML form, have to include

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

In controller

```
public String getFormData (@ModelAttribute("userForm") @Valid UserForm userForm, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    ..
    Optional<UserForm> result = userRepository.findById(userForm.getId());
    if(result.isPresent()){
          UserForm user = result.get();
          user.setCountry(userForm.getCountry());
          userRepository.save(user);
     }
..
}
```

Comment: I'll look into this. Thanks